# Visual Studio 2013 Community - how to mark opening and closing HTML tags

Tags: html, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2012 (Pro) I used to get this marking of the current focused HTML tag:

[image]

(notice the gray background of the opening and closing tags of TR)

For some reason, I don't have this on my current VS13 Community...

Is it deprecated in this version or is it a matter of setting the right background colors for this feature? If it's the latter, then what is the exact name of this option under the colors settings in VS?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more investigation on this got me to realize that this is indeed a matter of setting the right colors (which I don't have a clue how they changed "by themselves", but that's another issue).

Anyway, this is called Highlighted Reference under the colors settings.